# How to find the next availability of unique combination of file columns using shell scripts

Tags: shell, awk

I want to get the time difference of the rows which has unique combination of file columns.

Ex:

```
C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:00:56||I/O|12413508|2266556|2253044|300
C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:02:11||Driver text|40|1048536|1048532|300
C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:04:07||Processor|40750784|25825000|16768820|300
C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:05:56||I/O|12413508|2266556|2253044|300
C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:07:11||Driver text|40|1048536|1048532|300
C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:09:07||Processor|40750972|25824812|16768820|300
C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:10:56||I/O|12413508|2266556|2253044|300
C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:12:11||Driver text|40|1048536|1048532|300
C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:14:07||Processor|40750972|25824812|16768820|300
```

In this above file sample, I  am making unique combination of 1st and 7th column.And finding a time difference of next available same combination , example consider first row in this I am checking unique combination of 1st and 7th column  'C', 'I/O' looking for next available combination of same .

```
C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:00:56||I/O|12413508|2266556|2253044|300
```

Next available row with same combination

```
C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:05:56||I/O|12413508|2266556|2253044|300
```

This is my trial code  but i am not getting proper answer :

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {k=$7 FS $7} k in a{print $1,$7,$5"-"a[k]} {a[k]=$5}'  'M02232016.IGA-US-TESTFEED.dat' times |  column -t -s'|' | grep '/' | sort -u | head
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to print second instances of the unique combinations of $1 and $7?

Comment: I want the time difference(column 5)  between  combinations of $1 and $7  and next available instance of that combination

Comment: your code doesn't even attempt to take a difference though!  Can you post what end result you want to get.  Here there will be two differences (among three instances) for each key.

Comment: Take an example of this line  :C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:00:56||I/O|12413508|2266556|2253044|300 , And it has search next available combination of column 1 and 7 th and its time difference .                   C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:05:56||I/O|12413508|2266556|2253044|300,  Result should be  00:00:56   ,   00:05:56, Like this It has to find out all $1 and $7 th combination and its next available instances time difference...

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find the second instances of the unique combinations you can use this

```
$ awk -F'|' '{a[$1,$7]++} a[$1,$7]==2' file

C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:05:56||I/O|12413508|2266556|2253044|300
C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:07:11||Driver text|40|1048536|1048532|300
C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:09:07||Processor|40750972|25824812|16768820|300
```

But, perhaps you're trying something else.  If so, please update the original post with details.

Here is the pairwise differences for the times

```
$ awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}
                {k=$1 FS $7}
          k in a{print $1,$7,$5"-"a[k]} {a[k]=$5}' times | 
  column -t -s'|'

C  I/O          00:05:56-00:00:56
C  Driver text  00:07:11-00:02:11
C  Processor    00:09:07-00:04:07
C  I/O          00:10:56-00:05:56
C  Driver text  00:12:11-00:07:11
C  Processor    00:14:07-00:09:07
```

and this computes the seconds

```
$ awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}
                  {k=$1 FS $7}
            k in a{split(a[k],p,":"); 
                   split($5,n,":"); 
                   t=((n[1]-p[1])*60+(n[2]-p[2]))*60+n[3]-p[3]; 
                   print $1,$7,$5"-"a[k],t} {a[k]=$5}' times | 
  column -t -s'|'          

C  I/O          00:05:56-00:00:56  300
C  Driver text  00:07:11-00:02:11  300
C  Processor    00:09:07-00:04:07  300
C  I/O          00:10:56-00:05:56  300
C  Driver text  00:12:11-00:07:11  300
C  Processor    00:14:07-00:09:07  300
```

Comment: Yes, How much second difference between their occurence  means , 1st instance is                                                                                               C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:00:56||I/O|12413508|2266556|2253044|300                                                             2nd intsance is   C|IGA LA TESTFEED|mpg-fa-29-9-AnacDu23.gdl.mex.ibm.com|03/07/2016|00:05:56||I/O|12413508|2266556|2253044|300

Comment: @ karakfa  , thanks for solution.   Your calculation is almost correct, in this case I am looking for next instance of unique combination. ex: C  I/O , we need to looks next combination of  C  I/O  and its date time column. Please update your solution.

Comment: Output should be like this :                                                                    C  I/O          00:05:56-00:00:56  300
C  Driver text  00:07:11-00:02:11  300
C  Processor    00:09:07-00:04:07  300
C  I/O          00:10:56-00:05:56  300
C  Driver text  00:12:11-00:07:11  300
C  Processor    00:14:07-00:09:07  300

Comment: If you're only looking for a specific key value, just replace `{k=$1...}` with `{k="C" FS "I/O"}`